# How can I use a custom domain with Google App Engine?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, google-app-engine

I have purchased a domain from GoDaddy and I want to host it using Google App Engine. But when I added it to the app's custom domain, it asked me to sign up for "Google Apps for Business" (it is a trial for 30 days), to verify that I was the owner of the domain.

So will I also lose hosting on my custom domain by Google App Engine when the trial period expires?

I don't even want the account on  Google Apps for Business. Is there a way to add a custom domain to my app without signing up for Google Apps for Business?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a custom domain with Google App Engine, you would follow the steps here:  [Google App Engine:  Using a Custom Domain](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain)

When you get to step number 3 there, be sure to click:

`Sign up for a free single user Google Apps account`

After this, as written there:

"Proceed through the Google Apps signup process, either using an existing domain name or registering a new one."

Since you already have a domain name registered through GoDaddy, follow the steps for using an existing domain name.

Then you'll have to create a CNAME with GoDaddy to point your domain to the subdomain you created at `appspot.com`. Here are instructions on how to do this:  [GoDaddy: Adding or Editing CNAME Records](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7921/adding-or-editing-cname-records?locale=en)

You'll then have to wait 24-72 hours for DNS servers to update so that your domain name resolves properly.

For additional help,  there is a tag on StackOverflow that you can add to questions about Google App Engine. See this for more on that:  [Google App Engine community support is moving to Stack Overflow](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w)

There is also a support forum for GoDaddy domain name issues here:  [GoDaddy: Domain Management and Services Topics](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/domains-management-and-services/forum/)

**Update:**

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM/XPJYq1HUgusJ) post yesterday, the free, basic version of Google Apps is being discontinued, and replaced with a $50/yr per user fee that includes:

"24/7 phone support for any issue, a 25GB inbox, and a 99.9% uptime guarantee with no scheduled downtime"

This won't affect existing users already using the free service (or educational organizations). See this for more information: [Changes to Google Apps for businesses](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/changes-to-google-apps-for-businesses.html)

They will however [offer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM/XPJYq1HUgusJ):  "A $50 App Engine credit for developers who need to purchase a new Google Apps for Business domain in order to associate a domain with an App Engine account."